# Get the top 10 of fans who have more friends that are fans of a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to generate a top 10 of fans of a page that have the highest number of friends that are fans of the same page?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it isn't. You can't get even the list of your page fans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of friends from a user, that user has to authenticate your app.

When authenticated (depending on what permissions you ask for http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) you can see if that user is a fan of your page by calling `me/likes` on the Graph API.  You can get friends from `me/friends`.

Then you might be able to do some sort of lookup to other users of your app to calculate who has the most friends who've liked that page too.